# Issue with Chrome Driver using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open Chrome Driver through selenium but it is giving me error.
I am aware that new chrome driver is now located as CfT.

here is the code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
   {
     BrowserVersion = "stable"
   };
   DriverFinder.FullPath(options);
   options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
   options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");

   IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I tried to give path but it still looking for older chrome driver version.

Comment: great. So what the error?

Comment: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 111
Current browser version is 119.0.6045.160 with binary path C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe

Comment: this does nothing ```DriverFinder.FullPath(options);```. You need to provide binaryPath to options object or try using this tutorial. Its in java but the core issue is the same https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver

Comment: as per my understanding Selenium 4.11 and above should automatically download the Driver but it does not work specifically for Chrome in my case
It is working for Edge and FF at my end

Comment: Share more details about the problem like error messages, logs, return codes etc.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was able to fix it. I found that in old legacy code, the previously code was written to download older chrome driver. 
DriverFinder.FullPath(options);
was referring that old path - this is why the mismatch was happening, I corrected that code and new stable chrome driver was downloaded